# Can changing user agent to android in jmeter recorded test send traffic from android devices even if no emulator is installed in my laptop?

Tags: jmeter

For load testing from different browser do we need to have all browser version on host machine or user agent change in existing script will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMeter acts on protocol level, it builds HTTP requests using Java code and [Apache HTTPClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) libraries by default.

If application you're trying to test logic differs depending on browser you can mimic different browsers by sending the relevant [User-Agent](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.43) header via [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager).

Also consider the following settings:

- configure your [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers to:

  - Retrieve all embedded resources
  - Use concurrent pool of 4-6 threads for this

  This way you will be able to replicate browser behaviour when it comes to working with images, CSS files, JavaScript files, etc.
- add [HTTP Cache Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) to represent browser cache
- add [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to mimic simulate browser cookies, deal with cookie-based authentication, represent sessions, etc.

Check out [How To Make JMeter Behave More Like A Real Browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) guide for more detailed explanation of the above recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

**No.**

A web-browser uses `User-Agent` to tell a server what kind of Browser and Operating System it uses. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent):

> This allows the web site to customize content for the capabilities of a particular device

If you recorded your script with Chrome, JMeter would tell the server it was Chrome, and the server would respond to JMeter as if it were Chrome. JMeter, however, *does not actually user Chrome in any way*. Similarly, if you were to change you `User-Agent` to `Android`, the server would just respond to JMeter as if it were an Android device.